# web page not fully displayed on galaxy s4 stock browser

Tags: android, html, css

this is my first post in stackoverflow.. hopefully I can explain well enough
without images.

http://www.sk8spot.kr -> this is my website.

Other phones (tested on iphone, galaxy s2's stock browser) browser display
all contents including the right banner. But galaxy s4's stock browser does
NOT display the right banner.. I have to zoom out in order to display the
right banner.

Is this CSS issue or some kind of setting on galaxy s4's stock browser?

Please refer to the following image 
- http://www.kimsq.co.kr/modules/forum/files/2014/07/09/16ac2775359898ffeff0ee241cc91b7f231140.jpg
(Right banner [in red area] is NOT displayed on galaxy s4's stock browser)

Anybody have an idea?

Thank you in advance for any comment!

hyung

Comment: your css - http://www.sk8spot.kr/_core/css/sys.css?nFlag=201407  is too long. Give some code. What is that banner div's id/class ? Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Not all mobile devices default to the same viewport size. Since the banner is not part of the page flow and is absoluted off to the side of a center aligned page you will need to take the extra space into account.

I don't have an s4 to test with but adding this viewport meta tag could be enough:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
```

but if that doesn't work you will need to expand the default viewport to fit in the right  banner:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1280, initial-scale=1">
```